# How to use click on a dropdown list in angular?

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

```
<div>
    <label> Categories </label>
    <select>
        <option *ngFor = "let category of categories"
                [value] = "category" 
                (click) = "onCategorySelected( category.name )">                
                {{category.name}}

        </option>       
    </select>
</div>
```

That function `onCategorySelected` is just not getting called.
I have to pass it the user selected value from the dropdown list.
What is the way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `option` tag does not support the `click` event. You can instead make use of the `change` event on the `select` tag. You are also assigning an object to the `value` attribute in the `option` tag which is incorrect. To assign an object as the value, you need to use `ngValue`, if not assign a unique id to your `value`, for eg. `[value]="category.id"`.

Try this instead.

```html
<select (change)="onCategorySelected($event.target.value)">    <!-- If you are using ngModel or formControl, get the value from there instead of using $event.target.value -->
    <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">
        {{category.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am thankful to you. I request you to point the webpage where these events like click and change w.r.t select or anything are listed. I want to see the API. I didn't know about the existence of the change event.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl You're welcome. You can check out the mozilla docs on [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). At the bottom of the page, the events fired by that particular tag are shown. As you can see,`option` has no events while `select` has `change` and `input` event.

Comment: Thank you again, I am surprised though. We are talking about Angular. Is there no angular's own documentation? Am I supposed to follow simple HTML's docs to know about angular?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
<select (change)="selectionChanged($event.target.value)">
    ....
</select>
```

`$event.target.value` will send the value of the option you changed